# Facebook object debugger getting 500 response code but only on some pages?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get facebook open graph action to work, however, the object debugger tells me it is getting response code 500 from the pages I want to use. When I try to paste the URL into  Facebook to share, sometimes it says runtime error and sometimes it works, sometimes it just gets part of the image.

For example: http://www.literrater.com/book/10
This fails the debugger entirely with a 500 code
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.literrater.com%2Fbook%2F10

That same URL works when posting a status, sometimes.

Any suggestions about what I can do to fix this or at least diagnose the problem?

Edit: The site is hosted on windows azure as an asp.net web site. The blog at http://literrater.com/blog is php and the OG debugger seems to like it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial view being called in a MOBILE only razor view was being accessed and throwing an error. So while it worked in a desktop browser it was likely crashing on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm was having this same problem, and I'm using partial views on the pages in question, but I'm not convinced it's a Mobile only view that is your problem.  Try the Open Graph debugger here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to see if that helps you diagnose your problem.  Are you using the og properties?  My page worked after I added the meta property="og:type" content="article" to the header. My homepage worked by setting the og:type to website, but that wouldn't work for other pages on my site.  I hope this helps you.